# Problema con parseo de fechas java

Tags: java, date, parsear

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
public Date bigInteger2date(BigInteger bigInteger) throws IllegalStateException {
    final String dateStr = bigInteger.toString();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");

    try {
        return dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ParseException");
    }
}
```

El paramtero de entrada que le mando es la siguiente:

```
1563876178942
```

Pero lo que tengo como respuesta dista mucho de los esperado:
[image: ISSUE]

Utilizo una [pagina de utilidad la cual me parsea fechas](https://www.timestampconvert.com). Y me muestra la fecha que tendria que ser.

¿Alguna idea de que esta pasando y como solucionarlo?

Un saludo.

**EDIT**
El parametro de entrada de la funcion lo obtengo de aqui

```
    Date date = new Date();
    date.getTime();
```

Comment: Entiendo que el parámetro de entrada es la fecha en mili segundos?

Comment: Es el resultado de haber generado una Date y haber realizado un .getTime sobre ese valor

Comment: La respuesta que han dado es correcta pero yo te aconsejo usar el Calendar en lugar de usar el Date es mucho mas practico cuando trabajas con fechas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás mezclando cosas distintas: lo que tienes como entrada parece ser lo que llamando [*Tiempo UNIX*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix), que es una forma de medir el tiempo habitual en computadoras. Es tan habitual que prácticamente cualquier lenguaje de programación lo entiende, por ejemplo Javascript:

```js
let d= Date(1563876178942);
console.log(d);
```

En Java el equivalente sería

```
Date d= new Date(bigInteger.longValue());
```

Puedes ver detalles en [el API de Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#%3Cinit%3E(long))

Lo que estás haciendo, en cambio, es tratar ese valor como si fuera una fecha en el formato `yyyyMMddHHmm`, es decir

```
yyyyMMddHHmm
1563876178942

1563-87-61 12:89
```

Que tras varias transformaciones para hacer que los datos tengan algo de sentido se queda en

```
1570-05-03 21:42
```

En cualquier caso, **si estás haciendo una aplicación nueva** no uses java.util.Date (es antiguo y propenso a causar bugs), usa el paquete java.time